# Cannot download shared folder from google drive to google colab via link because python init file needs to be scanned for viruses

Tags: python, pytorch, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have a google drive folder and google colab notebook that both need to be shared among multiple people. I need to import the folder into the colab workspace, though I don't want them to have access to my entire google drive, just the specific folder. (Link to [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BHpCP_P-x0jQ2ukEFktaeoD_5VkHAez_?usp=share_link)) My best code is below:

```
import gdown
url = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BHpCP_P-x0jQ2ukEFktaeoD_5VkHAez_?usp=share_link'
gdown.download_folder(url, quiet=True)
```

However, I get the following message:

```
Access denied with the following error:

    Cannot retrieve the public link of the file. You may need to change
    the permission to 'Anyone with the link', or have had many accesses. 

You may still be able to access the file from the browser:

     https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1SBHBGrwPYgqeNVOfnD6yLMN15Acos7BQ
```

My folder is available to anyone with the link, but I suspect it is because the file needs to be scanned for viruses. Is there any workaround? I have tried everything related, but cannot find a solution to my specific problem that fits my needs. Please help, thank you.

Comment: please refer to this [github thread](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/issues/146#issuecomment-1041083275)

Comment: I tried your highlighted method, as well as others in the thread, though none worked for me. I keep getting an "Internal Server Error". Could you try to recreate with my link? Thank you.

Comment: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uuj8L028mSLj82S6gO2PO_9dBAWq2hkn/view?usp=share_link"  this file seems to be the problem.

Comment: Yes, though what is the problem with it, it is just a init file, considering I need it to structure as packages, what could I do?